# show `slideToggle` only when click on div element and close `slideToggle` in another button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a slide toggle that slides from right to left. I have some `div elements` and I want when clicking on them `slideToggle` only show and doesn't close on click again that `div element`. Only close when clicking to button in `slideToggle`

How can i do that? [Here is my detailed code jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whgmct5k/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've transferred your jsfiddle to the StackOverflow code snippet below.

I've added an additional function `slideOpen()` to the code. The function checks to see if `is_collapsed` is `true`. If the condition is met, the function will open the slider.

The trick here is to set `is_collapsed` to `false` at the end of the function so it doesn't run the animation again and close the slider.

Now, the only way to close the slider is by clicking the open/close button that uses your `slideToggle()` function.

Please, run the snippet below to see this code in action. I've also added some comments to the `slideOpen()` function to explain what's happening.

```js
var easing = 1;
var animation_speed = 200;
var slider_width;
var is_collapsed = true;

function slideToggle() {
  is_collapsed = $('#btn').css("margin-right") == slider_width + "px" && !$('#btn').is(':animated');
  var sign = (is_collapsed) ? '-' : '+';
  if (!$('#btn').is(':animated')) {
    if (easing) $('.willSlide').animate({
      "margin-right": sign + '=' + slider_width
    }, animation_speed);
    else $('.willSlide').animate({
      "margin-right": sign + '=' + slider_width
    }, animation_speed);
  }
  (is_collapsed) ? $('.willSlide').removeClass('expanded'): $('.willSlide').addClass('expanded');
}

//function to open slide
function slideOpen() {
//if is_collapsed is true, animate div and open slider
  if (is_collapsed) {
    var sign = '+'
    $('.willSlide').animate({
      "margin-right": sign + '=' + slider_width
    }, animation_speed);
    //add expanded class to button when opened
    $('.willSlide').addClass('expanded')
    //set is_collapsed to false so it won't close slider on additional clicks
    is_collapsed = false
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  slider_width = $('#content').width(); //get width automaticly
  $('#btn').click(slideToggle);
});
```

```css
#content {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(97, 97, 97);
  width: 200px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-right: -200px;
}

#btn {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  right: 0px;
  background: rgb(117, 231, 117);
  top: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

.expandedTxt {
  display: none
}

#btn.expanded .expandedTxt {
  display: block
}

#btn.expanded .click {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="slideOpen()">button1</div>
<div onclick="slideOpen()">button2</div>

<div class="willSlide" id='content'></div>
<div class="willSlide" id='btn'>
  <span class="click">open</span>
  <span class="expandedTxt">close</span>
</div>
```